# Due to the Button class, it is not possible to process events from the keyboard. JavaFX (changed)

Tags: javafx

I am writing a primitive java game using javafx.
I do the pause function by pressing the button
`@FXML private Button btnPause;`
The pause is regulated by the field `private boolean isPause`that changes in the method
 `@FXML private void pauseClick(ActionEvent event){ isPause = !isPause; }`
In the HelloApplication class, I handle keyboard events.

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
                HelloController.jump = true;
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.D)
                HelloController.right = true;
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.A)
                HelloController.left = true;
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.D)
                HelloController.right = false;
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.A)
                HelloController.left = false;
        });
```

I tested and found out that pressing any key on the keyboard is read by the program as pressing a button. That is, the presence of the button, and not the method that handles it, causes the problem.
How can I handle keyboard events and button clicks at the same time?

It's my code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 711, 400);

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
                HelloController.jump = true;
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.D)
                HelloController.right = true;
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.A)
                HelloController.left = true;
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.D)
                HelloController.right = false;
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.A)
                HelloController.left = false;
        });

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle bg1, bg2, player, enemy;

    @FXML
    private Button btnPause;

    @FXML
    private Label labelPause;

    private final int BG_WEIGHT = 711;

    private ParallelTransition parallelTransition;
    private TranslateTransition enemyTrans;

    public static boolean right = false, left = false, jump = false;

    private boolean isPause = false;

    private int playerSpeed = 3, jumpSpeed = 4;

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long l) {
            if (jump && player.getLayoutY() > 60f)
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() - jumpSpeed);
            else if (player.getLayoutY() <= 185f){
                jump = false;
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() + jumpSpeed);
            }

            if (right && player.getLayoutX() < 100)
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() + playerSpeed);
            if (left && player.getLayoutX() > 0)
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() - playerSpeed);

            if (isPause && !labelPause.isVisible()) {
                labelPause.setVisible(true);
                playerSpeed = 0;
                jumpSpeed = 0;
                parallelTransition.pause();
                enemyTrans.pause();
            }
            else if (!isPause && labelPause.isVisible()) {
                labelPause.setVisible(false);
                playerSpeed = 3;
                jumpSpeed = 4;
                parallelTransition.play();
                enemyTrans.play();
            }
        }
    };

//    @FXML
//    private void pauseClick(ActionEvent event){
//        isPause = !isPause;
//    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        TranslateTransition bgOneTrans = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(5000), bg1);
        bgOneTrans.setFromX(0);
        bgOneTrans.setToX(BG_WEIGHT * -1);
        bgOneTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

        TranslateTransition bgTwoTrans = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(5000), bg2);
        bgTwoTrans.setFromX(0);
        bgTwoTrans.setToX(BG_WEIGHT * -1);
        bgTwoTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

        enemyTrans = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(3500), enemy);
        enemyTrans.setFromX(0);
        enemyTrans.setToX(BG_WEIGHT * -1 - 200);
        enemyTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        enemyTrans.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        enemyTrans.play();

        parallelTransition = new ParallelTransition(bgOneTrans, bgTwoTrans);
        parallelTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        parallelTransition.play();

        timer.start();
    }

}
```

fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="711.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.realgame.HelloController">
   <children>
      <Rectangle fx:id="bg1" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#e2ff1f" height="400.0" stroke="#ffffff00" strokeType="INSIDE" width="711.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="bg2" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#26ff00" height="400.0" layoutX="709.0" stroke="#ffffff00" strokeType="INSIDE" width="711.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="player" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#13b734" height="124.0" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="225.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="124.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="enemy" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#c51212" height="87.0" layoutX="853.0" layoutY="264.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="87.0" />
      <Label fx:id="labelPause" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="239.0" layoutY="109.0" text="PAUSE" textFill="#4d0aff" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font name="Bell MT Bold" size="84.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnPause" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="18.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pause" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you have the key handlers in the Application class. I think they should be in the Controller.

Comment: @SedJ601 Typically you want to register key handlers with the scene, which is not defined in the FXML file. So it makes sense to register them in the place where the scene is created.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more completely? You say there is a "conflict". Does this mean the key handlers work if the button doesn't have an action handler registered? Or that they work until the button is pressed? Or something else? And can you make this so we can run it, by replacing the images e.g. with shapes?

Comment: @James_D, I agree to a certain extent, but there are ways to get the scene in the Controller.

Comment: See how [event handling works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD). There is a capturing phase, then a bubbling phase. Event filters are executed during capturing and Event handlers during bubbling. If something consumes an event during processing, it won't bubble back up to the scene to be handled. You may wish to process your key events in the scene by adding filters rather than setting handlers.

Comment: @James_D. I tested and found out that pressing any key on the keyboard is read by the program as pressing a button. That is, the presence of the button, and not the method that handles it, causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Unless I'm misunderstanding the intention, your code works as intended for me. Pressing `Enter` makes the rectangle jump; pressing `A` and `D` move it left or right, respectively.

Comment: @James_D Enter processing for Buttons on Windows differs from Macs, which is probably why you were unable to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Set focus traversal to false on the button which is consuming events.

```
<Button fx:id="btnPause" focusTraversable="false"/>
```

**Explanation**

See how [event handling works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD).

There is a capturing phase, then a bubbling phase.

- [Event filters](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addEventFilter(javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler)) are executed during capturing
- [Event handlers](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addEventHandler(javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler)) are executed during bubbling.

If something consumes an event during processing, it won't bubble back up to the scene to be handled.

This is what happens when you add a button to your scene.

A button can take focus and receive input.  When you only have one button, then it has focus, because there is nothing else to focus on.

Once the button has focus, it is hardwired to accept input from the keyboard.  If it accepts the input it will consume it, and the input won't bubble back up to your event handler in the scene.

There are certain key events that a button will handle.  You can see that in this code from the `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior` class:

```
// create a map for button-specific mappings (this reuses the default
// InputMap installed on the control, if it is non-null, allowing us to pick up any user-specified mappings)
buttonInputMap = createInputMap();

// add focus traversal mappings
addDefaultMapping(buttonInputMap, FocusTraversalInputMap.getFocusTraversalMappings());

// then button-specific mappings for key and mouse input
addDefaultMapping(buttonInputMap,
    new KeyMapping(SPACE, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, this::keyPressed),
    new KeyMapping(SPACE, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, this::keyReleased),
    new MouseMapping(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, this::mousePressed),
    new MouseMapping(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, this::mouseReleased),
    new MouseMapping(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, this::mouseEntered),
    new MouseMapping(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, this::mouseExited),

    // on non-Mac OS platforms, we support pressing the ENTER key to activate the button
    new KeyMapping(new KeyBinding(ENTER, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED), this::keyPressed, event -> PlatformUtil.isMac()),
    new KeyMapping(new KeyBinding(ENTER, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED), this::keyReleased, event -> PlatformUtil.isMac())
);

// Button also cares about focus
control.focusedProperty().addListener(focusListener);
```

Any keys in the input map will be consumed by the button if the button has focus.

The focus traversal keys are added to the input map (these are the up, down, left, right arrow keys), so the focus traversal mechanism consumes those keys and your left and right arrow key handlers in the scene don't work (the alternate keys for navigation that you have (D and A) do work because they aren't consumed).

The Enter key handler in your application works on a Mac, but not on Windows. Windows has special processing for handling Enter key presses for buttons, which will consume enter keys on that platform.

**General input handling methodologies**

Here are some alternative fixes:

1. Don't let the button have focus unless your application is in a state where it is OK if the button consumes the events (e.g. the game is paused).

   - The suggested solution above of switching off focus traversal for the pause button adopts this strategy.
2. Use event filters rather than event handlers in the scene and intercept events before the button consumes them.

   - A side-effect of using filters is that *both* your application and the button might action the event (if you don't consume it in your filter).  That might be OK or might not, depending on what you want.
   - Or, if do consume the event in the filter, then the button can't action it, which again might be OK or might not.

To fix the focus traversal issue, switch off focus traversal for the pause button.  In your FXML for the button write:

```
focusTraversable="false"
```

You already have that for setting for the Label in your FXML (which is redundant because a Label by default is not focus traversable), but you don't have it for the button.

Once focus traversal is set to off for the button, your left and right arrow navigation key handlers for your game start to work.

Setting focus traversal to false on the button also fixes the Enter key issue on windows, because the button won't consume the Enter key if it doesn't have focus and it can't retain focus because it is not part of the focus traversal graph.